# XDomainRequest performance issue while receiving base64 image

Tags: javascript, c#, xdomainrequest

I have two applications. One of them is an HTML based web application which works in IE9 mode and which receives scanned documents' images in base64 string format via XDomainRequest.

The other application is a Windows service written in C#. It listens requests on a port via HttpListener. Then it scans document and sends scanned image via HttpListenerResponse.

The scanned images will be processed by the web application on client side and then they will be uploaded to the server. So I have to do all job in javascript. There is not a server side solution (for now).

If I receive just one image it is not a big problem. But if the sender sends multiple images, base64 string becomes too large and it takes too much time.

I use below code to convert image to base64 string:

```
public static string ImageToBase64(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(ms, format);
                byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                return base64String;
            }
        }
```

And the below code is used to receive images:

```
 if (xdrScanning.responseText != "") {

         try {

                json = JSON.parse(xdrScanning.responseText);

                $('#scannedImage').attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64, ' + json[0].BASE64IMAGE);

              } catch (e) {
                 xdrScanningError();
              }
}
```

For all I know XDomainRequest receives string responses only.

So, what can I do to overcome that performance issue?

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is to load the data as binary data (not text) and load it using conversion methods similar to http://emilsblog.lerch.org/2009/07/javascript-hacks-using-xhr-to-load.html. But this method also is not very fast either.